# Multiple Countdowns using Keith Wood's countdown

Tags: jquery, countdown

I have a page with several countdowns on it, however for some reason they are all being counted down together, my current code is:

```
$("[data-date]").each(function(event){
    $(this).countdown({ since: $(this).data("date") });
})
```

My question is how can I use his library to have several countdown/countup timers on the same page?

Comment: sounds like your dates are the same, or possibly undefined or invalid format? Create demo that replicates problem

Comment: You are a genius! I can't believe I didn't think of the formatting!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else, the reason why was I hadn't converted my date to the correct format, the final code is below:

```
$("[data-date]").each(function(event){
    $(this).countdown({ since: new Date($(this).data("date")) });
})
```